# How to use a mask in Angular and pattern Regulars Expressions

Tags: regex, angular, typescript

I have a regular expression for OrcidId, 
the nomenclature is XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX with numbers of 0 to 9, in series of 4 numbers separator by "-".

and this is the code that I have made:

**in ts:**

```
 this.formIdentifier = this.builder.group({
      orcId: [ null, [ Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(this.maxLengthCharacters),Validators.pattern(constants.regex_orcid)]]
})
```

**in html :**

```
 <div class="input-container input-calendar inputleft">
            <label>{{'ui.label.orcid' | translate}}</label>
            <input mask="9999-9999-9999-9999" [(ngModel)]="orcId" placeholder="9999-9999-9999-9999" formControlName="orcId"/>
            <span *ngIf="!formIdentifier.controls['orcId'].valid && formIdentifier.controls['orcId'].dirty" class="error-message font-size-14">{{ 'ui.error.required' | translate }}</span>              
            <span *ngIf="!formIdentifier.controls['orcId'].pattern" >error</span>
          </div>
```

**in constants.ts :**

```
 regex_orcid:/^([0-9]{4})?(-)?([0-9]{4})?(-)?([0-9]{4})?(-)?([0-9]{4})?/
```

the problem is that it is not validating me and I don't know what I am doing wrong maybe the regular expression is wrong.

on the other hand is there a way to directly validate the mask without having to use a regular expression?
thanks to everyone.

the correction in Regulars expresions is :

```
/^([0-9]{4})?(-)?([0-9]{4})?(-)?([0-9]{4})?(-)?([0-9]{4})$/
```

Comment: Could you create a Minimal, Reproducible Example via StackBlitz? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: As you already using mask it is not required to add pattern validator for form control orcId.

Comment: but when removing the validation pattern, I do not get the desired error message either and it validates me as if it were fine. What I want is that if the specified text is wrong, the error will come out and do not let save.

Comment: On the subject of doing it with the regular expression I know it was wrong, the $ symbol was missing at the end, it would look like this:
/ ^ ([0-9] {4})? (-)? ([0-9] {4})? (-)? ([0-9] {4})? (-)? ([0 -9] {4}) $ /

Comment: you're mixing ngModel and form controls. this is bad practice and often leads to weird bugs